# Adding Entity References to Core Data

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data

II am trying to use Core Data for my iOS application and have been reading many tutorials and still really confused. Is using the iphone to add reference or adding them programmatically the only 2 ways to add row? I mean if I had a product catalog of 20 items I would need to type the code 20 times? Or could I just add row because the application is supposed to be read-only. Or am I just better off wth sqlite instead of Core Data? thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear: are you asking about adding data to the Core Data store before the app ships? Are you asking about adding data after the app ships? Core Data stores data much like a database: you can add data by importing from a file that you include with the app, you can add data during development and ship the app with data already in the store, you can add data after shipping by downloading it from somewhere and adding it programmatically, or you can add data a row at a time as the user gives you information. It's just as flexible as SQLite -- more flexible in many ways.

Comment: yep. that's what im asking. for example I would like to add a row of data without actually touching to code behind or using the iphone/ipod to add. would there by any other way?

Comment: I'll ask a different way, pick one of the following: 1. You want to ship the app with data already in it, or 2. You want to add bulk data to the app after it is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to write a quick Mac app to do the editing, using the same data model file.

If you're using Xcode 3, do this. Create a new Mac app that uses Core Data, and drag in your data model (removing the default data model it creates for you). Then, open the .xib file for the Mac app's main window in Interface Builder. Switch back to Xcode and open the data model.

Pick the entity you want an editor for. Then hold down option (alt), and drag the entity from the data model editor into Interface Builder. It automatically creates a user interface for editing the database, which you can then save and run through Xcode.

Make sure that your Mac app is creating an sqlite data store (look through the code that Xcode created for you by default, it may have defaulted to XML and you'll have to change it). The file that app creates can then be dropped straight into an iPhone app.

Sadly, Xcode 4 can't do the automatic laying out of a database editing UI. If you're using Xcode 4, you'd have to lay out the UI manually.